# Search: a childrens' book in the 60s about a young boy who can travel between dimensions

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, parallel-universe

I read a childrens' scifi book in the 60s about a young boy whose parents (I think) were scientists. I think they were working on interdimensional travel before he is born, and when he is born he is gifted. He finds that he is able to 'turn sideways' into another dimension of geometrical shapes and he becomes made up of geometrical shapes too, and travels through it. 
I'm pretty sure he slips or turns into that dimension when other scientists are after him to study him. 
The cover had a line drawing of a boy made up of geometrical shapes.
Help? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: It is possible that you're thinking of the same book that was asked about at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33353/childrens-book-with-square-triangles-in-parallel-universe?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135905/looking-for-title-of-book-1970-about-an-interdimensional-traveler and 
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161301/book-identification-genius-girl-through-another-dimension?noredirect=1&lq=1 and one or two other times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Universe Between](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?711) (1965) by Alan E. Nourse.

- The book starts before the boy is born.  A group of scientists have created something like a hypercube.  It is a portal into the 4th dimension.  Unfortunately, all the people who go travel to the 4th dimension come back insane or in a coma; a tennis ball comes back inverted.
- A teen girl is sent through; her name is Gail.  She comes back damaged and says that the only way a person can adapt is if they go when they are a newborn. She was able to return by turning a "strange invisible corner."
- Fast forward 20 years, and Gail has a teen son of her own, Robert.  He has been going over the "Threshold" since birth.
- Getting to and from the other dimension involves turning a specific kind of corner or angle.
- One cover from the 60s is bright green and has a pencil drawing of Robert made of geometrical shapes.

[image: Cover of "The Universe Between" by Alan E. Nourse, description above]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  I agree that this does sound like a reasonable answer, but it was suggested in the comments to the question, and OP has said this isn't it.

Comment: @DavidW and yet they accepted the answer. Odd.

Comment: It’s not odd. Those other questions describe different parts of the book which I had no memory of until I have since re-read it.  When this latest response came in, it was detailed.  So calm your farm.